# Are counters (noun) physical things?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Card example: [Beckon Apparition (Gatecrash)](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366461)

There are a lot of cards that use counter as a noun. I did some Googling but I'm just not clear on what I need to use for counters.  Are they physical things I can buy and if so, what is a good online resource?  Can I just make do with coins or something?

Comment: Incidentally, Beckon Apparition isn't actually an example of what you're asking about because it creates a token, not a counter. A token represents a permanent of its own, whereas counters have to be placed _on_ a permanent. You can use the same physical objects to represent counters and tokens, but there are also actual token cards you can get that come out of booster packs.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you talking cards like Angel that have 4/4 and then the ad on the back?

Comment: Yeah, those would be Angel tokens. (Of course the part on the back doesn't matter)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, counters should be represented by physical objects.

> 122.1. A counter is a marker placed on an object or player that modifies its characteristics and/or interacts with a rule, ability, or effect. [...]

There has been official products for use as counters. [Punch cards](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Punch_card) including -1/-1 counters and brick counters were provided alongside the Amonkhet block (Apr 2017). To help support the keyword counters it introduced, the Ikoria set (Apr 2020) provided punch cards with +1/+1 counters and keyword counters.

[image: Ikoria Counters]

You aren't required to use these. The objects used as counter can be anything. Dice and flat-bottomed glass beads meant to be used in flower vases are popular. You can get the latter at Michaels or Jo-Ann, among others. Some gaming stores carry them as well.

[image: Beads]

I've seen people use pennies, but they will scratch your cards if the cards aren't protected. (Anything could, but beads and dice have rounder edges.)

Comment: Using dice works as well, especially if you begin to get multiple counters.

Comment: @Discord - As long as you don't knock the dice over.

Comment: At a desperate pinch, when absolutely nothing else has been available, I have even used other cards (face down and offset stacked) as counters. Unwieldy, inelegant and annoying, but better than nothing.

Comment: Note that using other cards is forbidden in the context of a sanctioned event :)

Comment: For what it's worth, Wizard's internal R&D uses beads.

Comment: I like tiny d6s; people often have them for minis wargames and RPGs (it's nice to have two different colors). For planeswalkers I'll use a bigger die with numbers on it because I find it easier to think about the cost of their abilities that way.

Comment: A good alternative is a set of Go stones. Cheap ones can come very cheap (fancy ones can get very expensive, being hand carved from shells or precious stones) and at 180 per colour in a set you're highly unlikely to run out :)

Answer (score 6):

From the Magic Rules:

> 100.2. To play, each player needs his or her own deck of traditional Magic cards, small items to represent any tokens and counters, and some way to clearly track life totals.

and

> 121.1. A counter is a marker placed on an object or player that modifies its characteristics and/or
>   interacts with a rule, ability, or effect. Counters are not objects and have no characteristics. Notably,
>   a counter is not a token, and a token is not a counter. Counters with the same name or description
>   are interchangeable.

Any object will do to mark counters on a card. I tend to use D6s, although there are rare occasions when I have to use D10s or D20s, depending on the card. I find it easier to keep track of the number of counters on a card if I am using dice to mark them.

Comment: A big part of that for me is that I have a ton of random dice laying around that I've collected over the years. This seems like the best use for them.

Comment: You should just start with the d20s; be optimistic that you might put more than ten +1/+1 counters on that creature!

Answer (score 1):

I always use dice, which makes it real easy to keep track even if you have a lot of counter.
i got something like [this](http://www.awesomedice.com/dice-sets/36d6-dice-sets).